# Skip Certain folders in S3 Lifecycle Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I want to apply a deletion rule to my whole bucket to delete all objects that are older than 2 weeks. But my bucket has certain folders that need to be skipped. So is it possible via S3 lifecycle management to skip certain folders and delete rest of the stuff that is older than 2 weeks?

Here is my current bucket structure

```
- example-bucket.com
    - folder 1
        - images
            - 1. jpg
        - videos
            - 1.mp4
            - 2.flv
    - folder 2
        - images
            - 1.jpg
    - folder 3
        - videos
            - 1.mp4
    - folder 4 (Should not be deleted)
        - content
        - folders
    - folder 5  
        - images
            - 1. jpg
        - videos
            - 1.mp4
            - 2.flv
    - folder 6 (Should not be deleted)
        - content
        - folders
```

I want to skip folder 4 and 6 and want to delete stuff in all other folders that are 14 days old.

Can someone tell me if its possible via AWS S3 Lifecycle management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. `Lifecycle Rule` supports `prefix/tag` to filter what you want to apply the rule.
You need to define which you want to delete except others.
[Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html):

> To apply this lifecycle rule to all objects with a specified name
>   prefix (i.e., objects whose name begins with a common string), type in
>   a prefix. You can also limit the lifecycle rule scope to one or more
>   object tags. You can combine a prefix and tags. For more information
>   about object name prefixes, see Object Keys in the Amazon Simple
>   Storage Service Developer Guide. For more information about object
>   tags, see Object Tagging in the Amazon Simple Storage Service
>   Developer Guide

Comment: But I have countless folders & I cannot just write all of them as prefixes and the folders keeps on growing so is it possible to skip just 2 folders and apply lifecycle policy to rest of the stuff?

Comment: So you should add `tag` for your folders. You can add tag: `deletable:true` and `deletable:false` when you add new folder. So just apply `delete lifecycle rule` for folders with tag `deletable:true`

Comment: is there an easy way to do so like delete folders that do not have tag deletable: true? because folders are too many and I cannot add tags to everything

Comment: No, it does not support that way. I don't know why you don't want to implement it. There are 2 ways: 1. update `tag` for all your current folders/files. add more code into your source code to add `tag` to new folder automaticaly. modify rule as I suggested. 2. Use other services like `AWS Data Pipeline` or `Lambda` with schedule `every day` to check and do archive your old files/folders except some special folders. but you must implement by your hand.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes according to AWS support desk. Its the only possible solution as of now

Comment: There are no folders in S3, only object prefixes. You cannot tag a prefix, only an object.

Answer (score 1):

It's really frustrating but it isn't possible without adding every single prefix in the bucket that you want archived or deleted or labelling everything you want deleted, so if you are adding new folders to the bucket you will have to make sure that they conform to the prefix or are tagged which makes a maintenance nightmare. It would be much simpler if you could add an exception tag, particularly if you want a readme in the bucket describing what is in it that isn't archived.

Comment: better to add as comment rather than this to be an answer. It does not have the complete ANSWER flavor.